# Computation of $\sup_{x}\inf_{y} 4yx-x-2y$

Tags: calculus, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I would like to compute $\sup_{x}\inf_{y} 4yx-x-2y$ and $\inf_{y}\sup_{x} 4yx-x-2y$ where $x,y\in[0,1]$.

Since I had no idea to how to tackle the problem, I tried to take the derivative (1) with respect to $x$ when looking for the infimum over $y$ and (2) the derivative with respect to $y$ when looking for the supremum over $x$.

I get for (1)

$$
4x-2 =0 \implies x=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Thus plug this in the expression I found $2y -\frac{1}{2} - 2y = -\frac{1}{2}$ thus the supremum over $x$ of $4yx-x-2y$ seems to be equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$ and thus $\inf_{y}\sup_{x} 4yx-x-2y= -\frac{1}{2}$.

Similarly when I take the derivative with respect to $y$ for (2) I get

$$
4y-1 =0\implies y=\frac{1}{4}
$$

Plug in this un the expression I get $x-x-\frac{1}{2}$ so $\sup_{x}\inf_{y} 4yx-x-2y=-\frac{1}{2}$

I think the result is good because I should find that there are equal which is the case. **However** I do not understand why it works by taking the derivative with respect to the variable $x$ when I want to find the infimum over $y$ and vice versa.

Someone has an explanation please ?

Answer (score 1):

It worked because the [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)#Several_variables) $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4})$ of $f(x,y)=4yx-x-2y$ is a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point), but I do not recommend the use of derivative here. It suffices to apply the definition of $\sup$ and $\inf$ in the given order.

As regards the first one we have that, if $x\in [0,1]$ then
$$\inf_{y\in [0,1]} (4yx-x-2y)=\inf_{y\in [0,1]} (2y(2x-1))-x=
\begin{cases}
0(2x-1)-x=-x &\text{if $x\in [\frac{1}{2},1]$,}\\
2(2x-1)-x=3x-2 &\text{if $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.}\\
\end{cases}$$
Hence
$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]}(\inf_{y\in [0,1]} (4yx-x-2y))=-\frac{1}{2}.$$
Can you verify that
$\inf_{y\in [0,1]}(\sup_{x\in [0,1]} (4yx-x-2y))=-\frac{1}{2}$
by using a similar approach?

Comment: I think you missed the main question: Why does the use of derivatives lead to the correct answer in this case?